# Testing my network using aircrack-ng not working

Tags: encryption, wifi

I an using Fedora 17 With Intel 5100 card. When I execute the  command:

```
[root@fedora user]# aireplay-ng -9 mon0
10:26:46  Trying broadcast probe requests...
10:26:46  Injection is working!
10:26:48  Found 1 AP 

10:26:48  Trying directed probe requests...
10:26:48  02:22:FA:03:34:45 - channel: 11 - 'testnet'
10:26:48  Ping (min/avg/max): 2.015ms/6.429ms/9.232ms Power: -79.60
10:26:48  30/30: 100%
```

However when I try to test with the access point bssid, i get the following:

```
[root@fedora user]# aireplay-ng --test -e testnet -a 02:22:fa:03:34:45 mon0
10:28:50  Waiting for beacon frame (BSSID: 02:22:FA:03:34:45) on channel 11
10:29:00  No such BSSID available.
```

Can anyone help me on what is going wrong. I tried posting in the aircrack forum but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a kernel related issue and I have long wondered why it continues to be so. Ubuntu even removed aircrack-ng from their repositories. Anyway, there are kernel patches on the aircrack-ng website, or alternatively, you could create a bootable USB/DVD drive of backtrack-linux and use that. It's a pretty stupid problem, and I wish I could tell you why, but can only guess. And my guess would be cynical.

Specifically, the channel will not hold to that of the AP, no matter how many times you set it with iwconfig, airmon-ng, etc. Very annoying! Many probably think it is their wireless chip at first, but even the legendary rtl8187 suffers.

Also, the aircrack-ng forums do extensively cover this known issue, albeit in their own lingo. They generally don't respond to questions when what they consider answers exist on their forums. Admittedly, the solutions are not always perfectly clear.

Comment: Actually, I found what the error was. I was supposed to use aireplay-ng --test -e testnet -b 02:22:fa:03:34:45 mon0 (-b instead of -a). Thanks anyway for answering... I'll be marking it as correct :)